# Why does git ask for users' email address?

Tags: git, email-address

Why does git ask for users' email address, and include it in each commit?

Comment: because the Church of Scientology demanded it, probably so that they could contact the committers if they have concerns about a particular commit.

Comment: Nice try ... but I don't think Google indexes StackOverflow comments :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that someone else can know who committed the change.

By the way, it is a simple matter to configure git with a default email address for your commits.  It is explained in the Git SCM ebook:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

Comment: And because pull request could be made by sending patch by email. This way you are sure that people could communicate together (and email is the simplest thing that guarantee the identity of someone...)