# Can I make git config not supply the value of my email?

Tags: git, privacy, email-address

If I run `git config --get user.email`, it displays my current email address. Is it possible to configure git such that I can set a value of the email for a commit, but it won't display it with the `--get` switch?

Alternatively, can I just set an environment variable such that `git config --get user.email` won't get anything, but my commits will still have my email? Or can my commits use a unique identifier other than my email address?

I had a brief look at the git-config documentation page, looking for mentions of `--get` and "email". The environment variables look promising but I haven't tried them.

Related question: [Why does git ask for users' email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912322/why-does-git-ask-for-users-email-address)

Comment: What an odd requirement..... I know this looks like a rabbit hole but.... *why*?

Comment: @RomainValeri Moq recently attempted to get users’ (hashed) email address using that command: https://www.cazzulino.com/sponsorlink.html

Comment: If you want `git config --get user.email` to print nothing, I think you need to leave `user.email` unset. When you make a commit, specify `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` or use `-c user.email=xxx`. The value of these variables can be any string. It does not have to be an email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make `git config` unable to fetch the email that's used, because `git config` uses the same machinery as Git uses.  However, you can avoid setting (or unset) `user.email` and use the environment variable `EMAIL`, which will set the value if `user.email` and the Git-specific environment variables are not set.  I do this and it works great.

The full details are in [the `git-commit` manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_commit_information).